# Solr: How to use facet on values which has a whitespace

Tags: solr

I am a newbie to solr. I have installed solr(V 5.1.1) on my machine and index an csv file. I am using Solr Admin UI for doing queries. I am trying to filter my document by using facet where

```
q=sponsorship
fq=SEARCH INC
facet.field=Search_Tech

http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=sponsorship&fq=SEARCH+INC&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=Search_Tech
```

I am not getting proper results from facet if I do it on a value which contains a space(`for eg. SEARCH INC`). If **fq** contains a value **without whitespace**, I am getting proper results. I might be missing something. Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use %20 in between space,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=sponsorship&fq="SEARCH%20INC"&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=Search_Tech
```

and now it is working fine.

Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the fieldtype used ...?

Comment: fieldtype is "string"